# (IntelliJ) Maven adds png resource to jar, but doesn't use it

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, resources

I have a fairly simple Java program going with the following structure:

```
/src/main/java/  (all the classes in here)
/src/main/resources  (marked as resource root in IntelliJ, one png file in here)
/pom.xml
```

The way I build my Maven project is a bit of a workaround (because i couldn't get IntelliJ's artifact system to work). I have a run/debug configuration that builds the project using Command line: `install` (hope I'm explaining that sufficiently well).

Everything works fine, except for the inclusion of the `.png` file.
The weird thing is that the file is actually added to the executable `jar`, but somehow the final program doesn't appear to use it at all. It's accessed via:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource(url).toURI()));
```

Again, the final program works perfectly fine, except that the image is not visible at any point. Any help?

Edit: The `png` is located in the root folder of the `jar`, and the supplied URL is a string which is simply the name of the `png` file. I should probably add that the program works fine in the IntelliJ-Run-environment (including the `png`), but not using the executable `jar`.

Comment: Where in the jar is it? What is the supplied value of `url`?

Comment: I edited the original post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer that worked for me here:
[Access .png image in .jar file and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727212/access-png-image-in-jar-file-and-use-it)

Had to use

`img = ImageIO.read(MapObject.class.getResource(url));`

instead of

`ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource(url).toURI()));`

since the image was located in a `jar`.

Comment: Ah! It was the toURI() that was messing things up. Generally `getResourceAsStream()` will avoid issues like that.